# How to write my own AuthorizeTag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I ditching asp.net membership so I am guessing I need my own authorize tags(correct me if I am wrong). Since probably the ones they have all point to the membership classes(Not sure how to verify this though).

Now I tried to do this

public class MyTest : AuthorizeAttribute
{

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

    // Make sure the user is authenticated.
    if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I then in my defautl view I have this.

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("xiao", true);

I then have on another view

[MyTest()]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

I then go to this view and I am still able to access it. I see that it puts this in the url

```
"LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fAbout"
```

but bottom line it is I still can see the page(and all the content). When I should see just at the very least your not authorized or something like that.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Ok it seems to work now but I still don't know how to pass in roles.

Comment: Why are you ditching asp.net membership?

Comment: It does not meet my needs. I have stuff that it considers duplicate userNames since I am using more then the userName to determine the user. Since I do this I can't use any built in method. I have to write them all again. I also don't need most of the tables that it generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) and save yourself a lot of grief.

Answer (score 0):

A [Custom Role Provider](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/17/CreateCustomRoleProviderASPNETRolePermissionsSecurity.aspx) will also be helpful...